# What is term for a 'person who doesn't have own decision'?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the English word/term for a 'Person who doesn't have own decision' & do things only for others?

Comment: You mean submissive? :  of, tending towards, or indicating submission, humility, or servility.

Comment: @Josh61 Person who has some ambition his/her own but can't proceed/gets deviated because of other's suggestion. Ultimately, Single word for person who doesn't have his/her own final decision.

Comment: It's just called *indecisive*.

Answer (score 2):

*Slave,* *automaton,* *robot,* *puppet,* *cat's-paw* and *tool* all come to mind as possibilities.

However, they have different connotations:

*Slave* is closest to meeting both your criteria of lacking decision-making power and having to do what they are told.

*Automaton* and *robot* suggest someone whose emotional capacity is somehow stunted; they may or may not be carrying out someone else's orders.

*Puppet,* *cat's-paw* and *tool* all suggest that the individual is being manipulated into doing someone else's bidding.

Comment: Yeah..Robot is indeed cool for my purpose..Cheers..:)